How can I debug kubernetes source code on windows
I have installed vmware on my windows. I want to debug the kubernetes source code on windows, otherwise, I have installed centos on vmware. Can you provide the detailed step code?
windows10 and centos7.9
If  providing detailed information on which plugins are needed, it would be better.
Debug kubernetes code on windows

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What are you actually trying to do?  Do you have a sample workload so far?  A developer environment and a Go toolchain installed in your Linux environment?  Is the VM setup relevant to the question?
